# ESLint activate option to notify "Object is possibly null"

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

For some reason, my `.eslintrc.json` has some option, or has a lack of some option to catch the warning

> Object is possibly 'null'

What I need to change to eslint notify my about this warning?

**IMPORTANT** this is on my unit tests, so adding `strictNullChecks` does not work for my project, that why I asked if eslint has an option for that.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "latest"
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended", "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended", "prettier"],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": "off"
  },
  "ignorePatterns": ["dist/*"]
}
```

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "exclude": ["lib/**/*.spec.tsx", "lib/**/*.stories.tsx", "lib/**/*.styles.tsx", "settings/**/*", "dist/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDirs": ["lib"],
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true
  }
}
```

Comment: It is a typescript thing, you must enable it in `tsconfig.json` (strict option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was on the line:

```
"exclude": ["lib/**/*.spec.tsx", ...
```

Because of that, the tests are being ignored.

Answer (score 4):

In your tsconfig.json file under "compilerOptions", you want to set "strictNullChecks" to "true":

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strictNullChecks": true,
    }
}
```

That will make typescript warn you when a value is possibly null.  I don't think you can make eslint do it for you.

Comment: But this piece of code are on my unit tests, so... When I build my project that works anyways. That why I asked for a eslint solution

Answer (score 1):

ESLint cannot lint or warn about types only typescript can do it.

You want to have 2 `tsconfig.json` fles, `tsconfig.test.json` and `tsconfig.json`

The `tsconfig.json` should be like:

```
{
    ...
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strictNullChecks": true,
    }
}
```

and the `tsconfig.test.json` should be like:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    ...
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strictNullChecks": false,
    }
}
```

This way the script null check will **not** be checked during test run.

Comment: I want to be warned on null check on my tests, and I already have strictNullChecks true on my `tsconfig.json`

Comment: You cannot be warned about possible null objects. ESLint does not run type checking thus does not have the required info to warn about the possibility of the error.